# Why does the property not get set in this method?

Tags: ios

This is my method

```
- (void)populateLocationsToSort {

    //1. Get UserLocation based on mapview
    self.userLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:self._mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:self._mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude];

    //Set self.annotationsToSort so any new values get written onto a clean array
    self.myLocationsToSort = nil;

    // Loop thru dictionary-->Create allocations --> But dont plot
    for (Holiday * holidayObject in self.farSiman) {
        // 3. Unload objects values into locals
        NSString * latitude = holidayObject.latitude;
        NSString * longitude = holidayObject.longitude;
        NSString * storeDescription = holidayObject.name;
        NSString * address = holidayObject.address;

        // 4. Create MyLocation object based on locals gotten from Custom Object
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
        coordinate.latitude = latitude.doubleValue;
        coordinate.longitude = longitude.doubleValue;
        MyLocation *annotation = [[MyLocation alloc] initWithName:storeDescription address:address coordinate:coordinate distance:0];

        // 5. Calculate distance between locations & uL
        CLLocation *pinLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:annotation.coordinate.latitude longitude:annotation.coordinate.longitude];
        CLLocationDistance calculatedDistance = [pinLocation distanceFromLocation:self.userLocation];
        annotation.distance = calculatedDistance/1000;

        //Add annotation to local NSMArray
        [self.myLocationsToSort addObject:annotation];
        **NSLog(@"self.myLocationsToSort in someEarlyMethod is %@",self.myLocationsToSort);**
    }

    //2. Set appDelegate userLocation
    AppDelegate *myDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    myDelegate.userLocation = self.userLocation;

    //3. Set appDelegate mylocations
    myDelegate.annotationsToSort = self.myLocationsToSort;    
}
```

In the bold line, self.myLocationsToSort is already null.  I thought setting a value to nil was cleaning it out basically, ready to be re-used?  I need to do so because this method is called once on launch and a second time after an NSNotification is received when data is gotten from the web.  If I call this method again from the NSNotification selector, the new web data gets written on top of the old data and it spits out an inconsistent mess of values :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting it to `nil` removes the reference to that object.  If you are using ARC and it is the last `strong` reference to that object, the system autoreleases the object and frees its memory.  In either case, it does not "clean it out and be ready for re-use", you need to re-allocate and initialize your object.  If you would rather just remove all of the objects, and assuming `myLocationsToSort` is an `NSMutableArray` you can just call

```
[self.myLocationsToSort removeAllObjects];
```

Otherwise you need to do

```
self.myLocationsToSort = nil;
self.myLocationsToSort = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: The mention of "garbage collection" is wrong here. ARC does not in any way involve garbage collection.

Comment: @KenThomases What is it then?  Just automatically deleting the object when refcount=0?

Comment: Yes, it's reference-counted memory management. ARC simply automates the retains and releases.

Comment: Better but not perfect. There's no reason to believe the system autoreleases rather than simply releases the object. In general, setting a `__strong` variable will simply release the old value and retain the new. The setter for a `strong` property *may* autorelease rather than releasing if it's also atomic.

Comment: @ken I say "auto" because it is not something the user (coder) has to explicitly do

Comment: @DanF: Maybe changing "autoreleases" to "automatically releases" would avoid possible confusion...

Comment: @NSGod what is the difference?

Comment: @DanF, autoreleasing is a specific thing. It's a deferred release via the autorelease pool. "Automatically releases" does not have the implication of using autorelease pools and having deferred effect.